# How to add event listener to body element via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I add an `onload` event listener to the `<body>` element (or some other suitable near-top-level element) in an HTML document via JavaScript?

I want to achieve the same behavior as this:

```
<body onresize="handleResize();">
   ...
</body>
```

(i.e., when the page resizes, the function should run)

But I want to add the event listener with JavaScript like this

```
(function() {
  //effectively private because it's in the closure
  function handleResize() {
    //do stuff here
  }
  element.addEventListener("resize",handleResize);
})(); //IIFE
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to grab the appropriate element to attach the event to.

I tried this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("resize",handleResize);
```

And this:

```
document.body.addEventListener("resize",handleResize);
```

But in both cases, the `handleResize` function never gets called.

How can I access the appropriate top-level or near-top-level element?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("resize",handleResize);` usually does the trick. `window` is also the topmost object you can add an onload handler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the window element.

```
window.addEventListener("resize",handleResize,0);
```